# Place cursor on opening brace, press "=%", why does the closing brace get indented (in addition to desired indentation of lines between the braces)?

Tags: indentation

I am following along in the book *Vi IMproved* by Steve Oualline.

In Chapter 7, "Commands for Programmers", there is a discussion about indentation and the `=` command.

Here is what I wrote in my file

```
{
if True
return 1;
statement;
statement;
}
```

Then, as instructed by the book, I positioned my cursor on the first "{" and pressed "=%". The result was

```
{
        if True
        return 1;
        statement;
        statement;
        }
```

The book shows only the content within the braces being indented.

Why is the closing brace being indented?

Comment: The automatic indentation of the file generated by the `=` command (e.g. `=%` or `=G`) depend on your file type and your file type implementation. Your problem is probably laying there. Could you share your file type with us (`:set filetype`)?

Comment: The full output of `$ vim --version` might be relevant, too. Both the example from the book and the example from OP work as expected, here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automatic indentation of the file generated by the `=` command (e.g. `=%` or `=G`) depend on your file type and your file type implementation.

I can reproduce your problem when the filetype of the text (`:set filetype?`).

You have the odd behavior because the code block are not grouped with curly braces (`{` `}`) in Python.

If you select a file type that is curly base compatible you will not have that effect.

```
:set filetype=c
```

Comment: @evianpring of this solution solves your problem may ne could you validate it using the green v button next to the arrow voting button. Approving solution makes them rest ;-)

Comment: Indeed the issue happened in a python file.